# Serial hangs on Arduino-Uno

Tags: arduino-uno, serial, raspberrypi

I'm having issues with Arduino and RPI3 serial communication, it'll become unresponsive after a little time. Tried increasing BAUD rate and same issue, also happens on Windows as well so RPI is not at fault, and even after increasing the `delay` the hang still happens.

RPI3 python code

```python
import serial
import time

if __name__ == '__main__':
  ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyACM0', 115200, timeout=1, writeTimeout=0)
  ser.flush()
  last = "on\n"

  while True:
    last = "on\n" if last == "off\n" else "off\n"
    ser.write(last.encode())
    print(last)
    time.sleep(0.5)
```

Arduino code

```cpp
#define BAUD_RATE 115200
const int LED_PIN = 8;
String command;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(BAUD_RATE);
  pinMode(LED_PIN, OUTPUT);
  delay(100);
}

void loop() {
  Serial.println("I was written in RPI");

  if (Serial.available()) {
    command = Serial.readStringUntil('\n');

    if (command.equals("on")) {
      digitalWrite(LED_PIN, HIGH);
    } else if (command.equals("off")) {
      digitalWrite(LED_PIN, LOW);
    }
  }

  delay(50);
}
```

after less than a minute I'll get this exception from python

`BlockingIOError: [Errno 11] Resource temporarily unavailable`

The Arduino TX and RX led's stay on when it becomes unresponsive rather than flashing like it normally does.

Comment: `also happens on Windows as well so RPI is not at fault` ... maybe, but it does not exclude python problems

Comment: what error do you get on the RPi if you run LED blink sketch on the arduino?

Comment: Just the `resource temporarily unavailable`, the Arduino TX and RX led's stay on when it becomes unresponsive rather than flashing like it normally does.

Comment: the `if (!Serial) { }` block belongs in `setup()`

Comment: remove the `if (Serial.availableForWrite()) { }` block  .... whittle the code to minimum

Comment: Adjusted the code to be minimal.

Comment: does it still hang up?

Comment: Yes, still hangs

Comment: Does it help if you remove the `Serial.println()` from the Arduino code?

Comment: Can you try to find out _which_ resource is unavailable?

Comment: You are flooding the RPi/PC with `"I was written in RPI"` and don't read it. Does it work if you read `ser` regularly?

Comment: Does `dmesg -w` tell you anything at the moment it locks up?

Comment: Seems to work fine if all I do is read OR write on the Arduino even without reading from the serial in python.

Comment: @thebusybee you were correct, seems to be working with `ser.readline()` in the python code. Free points if you want to write the comment as an answer will accept.

Comment: Also, worth noting I had to increase the `delay` on the Arduino to be more than `sleep` in python. For me `delay(50)` and `sleep(0.01)` works fine, maybe has something to do with python being slow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are flooding the RPi/PC with `"I was written in RPI"` and don't read it. It will work if you read `ser` regularly.

On the delays: A message over a serial line has a transmission time, in your case 20 characters at 115200 baud from Arduino to RPi/PC. With the common 8n1 protocol, characters are sent at 11520 per second. With 20 characters this will take nearly 0.002 seconds, or 2 ms. The receiver needs a smaller delay than the sender to avoid overflows.

If the Arduino were using the USB directly (AFAIK it does not, between its USB interface and the actual AVR is a "real" serial line), the baudrate does not matter. A virtual serial line over USB is always really fast, independent of the announced baudrate. I once used 921600 baud with success. ;-) The baudrate is only used if a real serial line is involved.